# Maintain dropdown menu until navigated away from

Tags: jquery

I have the below code snippet and it's displaying my drop down menu ok but I can't seem to get the dropdown to stop there until the mouse moves away from the `ul.nav li a` selected of the mouse moves away from the dropdown box opened, any suggestions?

```
$("ul.nav li a").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
            $(this).parent().find('.dropdown').show();
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
            $(this).parent().find('.dropdown').hide();
    }
});
```

This is the menu code I'm using.

```
    <ul class="nav">
            <li class="first"><a href="/">HOME</a></li>
            <li>
                    <a href="#">CATEGORIES</a>
                    <div class="dropdown" style="display: none">test</div>
            </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Try to trigger the event from nav, show/hide at $("nav").on(... I yhink your menu is send a mouseleave event when mouse move between the letters of <a> (or between two <a>, if they are block)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `hover` event with in/out handler and `toggle` instead and target the `LI` not the `anchor`:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zh25j/)

```
$("ul.nav li").hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.dropdown').toggle();
});
```

Or use CSS...

Comment: only other issue here is that when the mouse is over the .dropdown fiv the li losses it's hover state, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to use jQuery for this, you can use pure CSS:

```css
ul.nav li div.dropdown {
    display: none;
}

ul.nav li:hover div.dropdown {
    display: block;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/9Ch8z/).

Just ensure to remove the `style` attribute from your `div` in your markup.

Rather than detecting the `:hover` on our `a` element, we're detecting it on the containing `li` element. When a user hovers over the `li` element, the `div.dropdown` element within is set to `display: block`.

Comment: CSS3 isn't supported by older browsers like IE8 & IE7.

Comment: @atallon I've edited my answer so that older browsers can use it.